# Which function should I use to insert an image inside the Card?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I updated the code because what I want is something like this...This is the card I want to make
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBU34.png)
I've tried several rearrangements in the code, but all I've got is to mess things up. I still want to be able to click and navigate to another page, as in the original version. I am having a lot of errors trying to adjust, since I'm a beginner in flutter I need help to correct and make this card.

My code is...

```
 // @dart=2.17
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:farma/ansioliticos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antiistaminicos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antivirais.dart';
import 'package:farma/analgesicos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antibiotico.dart';
import 'package:farma/antifungicos.dart';
import 'package:farma/antiinflamatorio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Farmacologia Odontológica',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: const Splash(),
    );
  }
}

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Splash> createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
    });
  }
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset('icons/Icone inicial.png', height: 230,width: 230,),
            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            if (Platform.isIOS)
              const CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              )
            else
              const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Farmacologia Odontológica',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf',
            fontSize: 22,
          ),
        ),
      ),

      body: Container(
        child:
        Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          ),
          Text('Classes de Medicamentos',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf',
                fontSize: 18,
              )),

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => analgesicos(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Column(
                    children:[
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'icons/Icone inicial.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
                          child: Text(
                            'Analgésicos',
                            style: productTitleStyle,
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]

                )
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Antiinflamatorio(),
                ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Anti-inflamatórios'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antibioticos(),
              ),
            ),

            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antibióticos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antifungicos(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antifúngicos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antivirais(),
              ),
            ), // issue was here
            child: const Material(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antivirais'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Antihistaminicos(),
              ),
            ), // issue was here
            child: const Material(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Anti-histamínicos'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Ansioliticos(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                                    title: const Text('Ansiolíticos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),)

        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vucv.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create a rounded box with an image and text right? To make a rounded box you can use a container and with a decoration. Then you can place text, and images inside the container. Here is an example code. You can also use Circle Avatar to give your image circular view. Let me know if this helps.

**Class Splash Code Updated**

```
class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Splash> createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/burgerhub.png',
              height: 230,
              width: 230,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            if (Platform.isIOS)
              const CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              )
            else
              const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Farmacologia Odontológica',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'fonts/Quicksand-Light.ttf',
            fontSize: 22,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
        child:
            Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          ),
          Text('Classes de Medicamentos',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf',
                fontSize: 18,
              )),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Container(
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'icons/Icone inicial.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
                      child: Text(
                        'Ansiolíticos',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 21,
                        ),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ])),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Anti-inflamatórios'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antibióticos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antifúngicos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ), // issue was here
            child: const Material(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Antivirais'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ), // issue was here
            child: const Material(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Anti-histamínicos'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ScreenLayout(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              child: (Card(
                elevation: 12,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Ansiolíticos'),
                ),
              )),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result Code]

Comment: I got the error lib/main.dart:117:26: Error: Expected ']' before this.
                    child: ClipRRect(
                         ^
lib/main.dart:117:21: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:farma/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
                    child: ClipRRect(
                    ^^^^^

Comment: updated the code. Check now!

Comment: I believe part of the problem is related to the size of my image. It is a png I made in Illustrator. How should I resize to fit the box? And by the way, if I want to create multiple boxes, how should I organize my cards with this new code?

Comment: To make it fit inside the box, I have used the fit property above. You can use the fit property. Please update the code and share more info about the error.

Comment: I substituted the code, but I got "too many positional arguments", error

Comment: Yes that was an example code. Can you update your ques with the main code where you are trying to size your image? I will take a look and share the updated code with you.

Comment: I've updated my question, and put the example of what I want to do. Plus I have pasted the code where I think it should be. Thank you once again

Comment: Update my answer with a new code please check and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine. Now I just have to make this page scrollable. My image did not fit well the space, but I'll redraw so its proportions match the ones of the box

Comment: Add the complete body inside SingleChildScrollView to make it scrollable. Most Welcome. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

you can user `Image.asset("image.png")`.
there are other widget which can show an image in `CircleAvatar` for having a circle shaped picture

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).